# Mac OSX: Cannot color broken symlinks

Tags: macos, terminal, colors, .bash-profile

On my linux machine, you can tell intact symlinks from broken ones, because broken ones are colored red. I've tried to set this up on my mac by adding some configurations to PSCOLORS in my .bash_profile, but so far nothing has worked. I've managed to get the coloring to tell apart directories, files, executables, and symlinks. However, the broken symlinks are not a different color than intact symlinks. Searching around on google hasn't rendered any promising results. Ideas? Tricks?

Comment: You might be successful in installing a port of Linux' `ls` that supports coloring symbolic links for their targets, and colors orphaned links. OS X's `ls` simply cannot do it. It's [150KB of source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/) vs. [25KB of source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-212.1/ls/)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it's possible – the man page for `ls` doesn't list a color slot for broken symlinks.

[Here's a handy `find` one-liner](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Shell/How%20to%20find%20broken%20symlinks.html) for finding broken symlinks:

```
find -L . -type l -ls
```

Answer (score 12):

Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) first.

1. Install GNU coreutils: `brew install coreutils`
2. Put the following in your `~/.bash_profile`: 

   `eval $(gdircolors)
   alias ls="gls --color=auto"`

Open a new shell, and broken links will be highlighted like on Linux.

Comment: don't forget to add the following alias in your ~/.bash_profile: `alias ls="gls --color=auto"`

Comment: As it is just an output of `dircolors`, you can as well just put `eval $(dircolors)` in your `~/.bash_profile` (if dircolors is installed)

Comment: Nice tips, I've added it to the answer. Thanks to @lorenzo.