# OS X: is there an application that can check for broken aliases in Finder?

Tags: macos, alias

I use a lot of aliases in my file system. Many original documents are placed in global repositories and I access them by aliases grouped in "tag" folders. Therefore, when I need to delete such a document, I need to check multiple tag folders to remove the aliases, which pains.

Is there an application that can check for broken aliases in Finder (or preferably, a particular folder)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not at my Mac to test this fully, but I believe that by using the command in a previous [SU answer](http://superuser.com/a/425851/19999) along with [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php), you can create a rule to either alert you to broken links, color them, delete them, etc.

Comment: @fideli `find -L . -type l -ls` only works with symlinks.

Comment: @LauriRanta Whoops, I thought Finder aliases are simply symlinks. Perhaps not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running something like this in AppleScript Editor:

```
set l to {}
tell application "Finder"
    try
        alias files of entire contents of (POSIX file "/Users/username/Folder/" as alias)
        -- zero aliases results in an error, one alias is not returned as a list
        result as list
    on error
        return
    end try
    repeat with f in result
        try
            original item of contents of f
        on error
            --move contents of f to trash
            set end of l to POSIX path of (f as text)
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
set text item delimiters to linefeed
l as text
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the application [alifix](https://eclecticlight.co/taccy-signet-precize-alifix-utiutility-alisma/) by Howard Oakley.

Comment: At the very least you should descibe *how* to use the software to solve the problem as asked in the question. [How do I recommend software in my answers?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers). How does this tool achieve what is asked? How do you use it? How do you set it up?